# Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 3 Invalid Column Name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I've been using an ADO.NET Entity Data Model in a project to test security/authorization methods I've been developing. I got everything working like I want and I need to mimic the behavior in another production project.

The other production product is using Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 3 to generate classes/entities and mapping classes. So far it only has Models and Mappings.

I have a Users table, Roles table, and UsersInRoles table (among others).

There is a 1-many relationship between Roles and UsersInRoles, but a 1-1 between Users and UsersInRoles.

I think I have the db relationship correct. The ADO Model seems to think so :)

But when I make a call to db.Users in my C# code when using the Power Tools generated classes I get:

{"An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details."}

{"Invalid column name 'Role_RoleId'."}

When I execute the EF command - View Entity Data Model DDL SQL I see a column named Role_RoleID, which is not correct...right?

There is no Role_RoleId in the database table Users. Also, UsersInRoles is not generated in the Model or Mapping files. **How do I fix this? I am at a loss.**

```
[...]
create table [Auth].[Users] (
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] not null,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](100) not null,
    [FullUserName] [nvarchar](100) not null,
    [Password] [nvarchar](150) not null,
    [PasswordSalt] [nvarchar](50) not null,
    [IsEnabled] [bit] not null,
    [IsLockedOut] [bit] not null,
    [Email] [nvarchar](150) not null,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] not null,
    [LastModified] [datetime] not null,
    [Role_RoleId] [uniqueidentifier] null,
    primary key ([UserId])
);
alter table [Auth].[Users] add constraint [User_Role] foreign key ([Role_RoleId]) references [Auth].[Roles]([RoleId]);
[...]
```

SQL Server Tables

[image: Diagram]

```
CREATE TABLE [Auth].[Users](
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [FullUserName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [PasswordSalt] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IsEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsLockedOut] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [LastModified] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [Auth].[Roles](
    [RoleId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [RoleName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Roles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RoleId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [Auth].[UsersInRoles](
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UsersInRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


ALTER TABLE [Auth].[UsersInRoles]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_UsersInRoles_Roles] FOREIGN KEY([RoleId])
REFERENCES [Auth].[Roles] ([RoleId])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE SET DEFAULT
GO

ALTER TABLE [Auth].[UsersInRoles] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_UsersInRoles_Roles]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Auth].[UsersInRoles]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_UsersInRoles_Users] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [Auth].[Users] ([UserId])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [Auth].[UsersInRoles] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_UsersInRoles_Users]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Auth].[UsersInRoles] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_UsersInRoles_RoleId]  DEFAULT ('8B24673F-A4FB-4031-9185-8CCBD96CBE4D') FOR [RoleId]
GO
```

CS files

```
public partial class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string FullUserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
        public bool IsLockedOut { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    }



  public partial class Role
    {
        public Role()
        {
            this.RoleSecurables = new List<RoleSecurable>();
            this.Users = new List<User>();
        }

        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<RoleSecurable> RoleSecurables { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }



public UserMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.UserId);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.UserName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(100);

            this.Property(t => t.FullUserName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(100);

            this.Property(t => t.Password)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(150);

            this.Property(t => t.PasswordSalt)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            this.Property(t => t.Email)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(150);

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("Users", "Auth");
            this.Property(t => t.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId");
            this.Property(t => t.UserName).HasColumnName("UserName");
            this.Property(t => t.FullUserName).HasColumnName("FullUserName");
            this.Property(t => t.Password).HasColumnName("Password");
            this.Property(t => t.PasswordSalt).HasColumnName("PasswordSalt");
            this.Property(t => t.IsEnabled).HasColumnName("IsEnabled");
            this.Property(t => t.IsLockedOut).HasColumnName("IsLockedOut");
            this.Property(t => t.Email).HasColumnName("Email");
            this.Property(t => t.DateCreated).HasColumnName("DateCreated");
            this.Property(t => t.LastModified).HasColumnName("LastModified");
        }



public RoleMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.RoleId);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.RoleName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(100);

            this.Property(t => t.Description)
                .HasMaxLength(250);

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("Roles", "Auth");
            this.Property(t => t.RoleId).HasColumnName("RoleId");
            this.Property(t => t.RoleName).HasColumnName("RoleName");
            this.Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("Description");
        }
```